# Optional hash prefix for angular routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, hashbang

I am currently trying to make an angular app indexable by implementing the _escaped_fragment_-scheme ([Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)). I am aware of the fact that it is deprecated but as far as I can tell after some research and experiments it is still the safest bet.

The scheme requires the hashbang `#!` as the delimiter for the 'real URI' and the angular routing part of the URI, i.e.

http://www.someuri.com/#!/dashboard

Currently I use the default #:

http://www.someuri.com/#/dashboard

I know how to change the routing to use '#!':

```
angular.module('myApp').config([  
    '$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);
```

However, this obviously breaks 'old' links (like http://www.someuri.com/#/dashboard).

**How can I route both URI formats correctly?**

I have tried to configure the routing like this:

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider
            .when('!/imprint', '/imprint')
            .when('!/blog', '/blog')
            .when('!/blog/{blogPostId}', '/blog/{blogPostId}');
    });
```

but it doesn't work, neither can I define states with an exclamation mark as the first character of the route's URI.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove ! from `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` to `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` and add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
 and at index page in head sectoin `<base href"/"/>`